# Looking for advice on how to store and access game information in my Android app

Tags: java, android

I'm currently making a simple RPG in Android Studio using Java, and am having trouble identifying the best way to store and modify the game variables, such as player name, money etc.

The videos and resources I have looked at have offered multiple solutions, such as passing the variables through to different intents using bundles, using singletons, using shared preferences or simply using static variables.

Originally, I was planning to use an instance of a 'PlayerInfo' class in the main activity to store the information, and use bundles to pass the data, however, as the data will be needed in almost every activity, is this the best way?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could you provide some small sample code to demonstrate what you have and help someone provide some input on what could be improved

Comment: To me, using a cloud is the easiest way, but this totally depends on what you are more familiar and comfortable with. It's really an open-ended question to be honest. Maybe if you provide some code and point out the sections where you want to store and pass data, we can offer solutions tailored to your situation.

Comment: In terms of code, I basically only have a framework of all the different activities, with buttons linking them. For example, the 'World Map' is the hub, which has buttons linking to other activities, such as a 'School' where there is a simple quiz, or a 'Shop' where they can spend money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal choice in your case would be to use `SharedPreferences` and store items as key value pairs! You can write to sharedpreferences file this way:

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), newHighScore);
    editor.commit();
```

And read from the Sharedpreferences file this way:

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.string.saved_high_score_default);
 long highScore = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), defaultValue);
```

Here is a complete [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm) on Sharedpreferences if you dind it hard!

**Note:** `Sharedpreferences` will only be a good option if the data you are saving is small, if your data is large and has relationships in between, would advice you to use [Sqlite](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm) or [Realm](https://realm.io/news/realm-for-android/)

Comment: Thanks this does seem like a better way forward, I'm only saving a few strings and integers so shouldn't have any size issues. I shall see what I can do!